# get filterable attributes of current product

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I need to generate a table of filterable attributes with values of current product, something like 
color - 3 
size - 5
x - y
...
In my view.phtml
Problem is: my shop will have many attribute sets, and attributes can change. So I can't get attributes value by name. 
I get an attribute sets code of current product, and retrieve all attributes of this set. But I don't know how filtered it by only filterable attributes?
Or maybe someone know simpler way to do this?

Thank you, and sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Roman, you can get all filterable attribute by below code. Modify/add your condition to get the specific data accordingly.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
    $collection
        ->setItemObjectClass('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')
        ->setOrder('position', 'ASC');
    $collection->addIsFilterableFilter();
    $result = array();
    foreach ($collection as $attribute) {
        $result[] = array('value' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(), 'label'=>$attribute->getFrontendLabel());
    }
```

Comment: tnx
How can i filter this collection by attributes set?

Comment: or something like  $attribute->getAttributeSet();